# How can I pause hover on an image while going over an overlapping div?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that I built with Bootstrap and jQuery with an image where I track the mouse movements with the hover and mousemove methods. Then I add tags on top of the image that mark the exact X and Y coordinates.

These tags have a close div that deletes the clicked tag. 
The problem is that when I click on the close div, it closes the tag div but the click generates another tag where the click happened.

How can I stop or pause the hover while it is on the overlapping tag so that it wont create another tag? Shouldn't it happen automatically since the focus is now on the tag?

Here is the problem replicated, I'm showing it with Bootstrap. I am using jQuery 1.9.0 and Bootstrap 3.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
.tempSpot {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 200;
    background-color: red;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tempSpot span{
    color: #000;
}
</style>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pgPosX = 0;
var pgPosY = 0;
var intTempSpot = 0;
var intSpots = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.imgDisplayTemplate .imgImage').hover(function(e) {
    }).mousemove(function(e){
           var imgOffset = $('.imgImage img').offset();
           window.pgPosX = Math.round(e.pageX-imgOffset.left-1);
           window.pgPosY = Math.round(e.pageY-imgOffset.top-1);
           if(window.pgPosX >= 0 && window.pgPosX < 640 && window.pgPosY >= 0 && window.pgPosY < 480) {
            $('.imgDisplay .imgAnalyze span.showTemp').html("X="+window.pgPosX+" Y="+window.pgPosY);
           }
    }).click(function(e) {
        if(window.pgPosX >= 0 && window.pgPosX < 640 && window.pgPosY >= 0 && window.pgPosY < 480) {
            window.intSpots++;
            window.intTempSpot++;
            var tag = "<div class='tempSpot' id='temp_"+window.intTempSpot+"' style='left:"+(window.pgPosX+15)+"px; top: "+(window.pgPosY)+"px;'>X="+window.pgPosX+" Y="+window.pgPosY+" <span> x</span></div>";
            $('.imgDisplay .imgImage').append(tag);
            $('.imgAnalyze button.TempSpotPost').css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    }); 

    //close a tempSpot 
    $('.imgDisplay').on('click', '.tempSpot span', function() {
        $(this).closest('div.tempSpot').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 imgDisplay">
      <div class="imgDisplayTemplate">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading imgHead">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Tag Test</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body imgBody">
            <div class="col-md-12 imgAnalyze">
              <h2><span class="label label-default showTemp">Y=0 X=0</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 imgImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" width="640" height="480">
                <div class="tempSpot" id="temp_1" style="left:220px; top: 250px;">X=220 Y=250<span> x</span></div>
                <div class="tempSpot" id="temp_2" style="left:129px; top: 116px;">X=129 Y=116<span> x</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `e.stopPropagation()`, which prevents an event from bubbling up the DOM tree and activating all the event handlers.

```
//close a tempSpot 
$('.imgDisplay').on('click', '.tempSpot span', function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).closest('div.tempSpot').remove();
});
```

Comment: Great! This totally did the job! @Kierchon was correct within the limited facts I offered, but this one solved my problem.

Comment: I would recommend changing it from a `span` to some class name like `.close`, that way it's semantic in your HTML and you aren't bound to a specific tag in the event you want to change to a `div` or something.

Comment: That's a good point. I used a `span` because I have an image on my actual page that I want to butt up to the text on the tag. But I could give the img the `.close` class. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.imgDisplayTemplate .imgImage').hover(function(e) {
```

to...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.imgDisplayTemplate img').hover(function(e) {
```

This will only make new boxes when the image itself is clicked not the surrounding div. When its being called on the surrounding div you get new boxes because the tempSpots are in that surrounding div.

http://jsfiddle.net/qy9Ht/1/

Comment: Your answer is correct but it wont work for me. And this is my fault since I did not include an important fact in my reduced example. On my full page I populate the image dynamically so that hover does not detect the img selector. That is the reason I'm using the div that does not change (ingImage).